# Python: Grid line drawn over plot_surface() in animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have been trying to animate a surface. So far all the animation works, and the surface is plotted nicely. Yet I have some straight lines on my surface that look like they are from the axis. Is there a way to get rid of this?

```
# Plot first figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
    vmin = 900, vmax = 1430, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

def data(i, X,Y,Z, surf):
    #change soln variable for the next frame
    ax.clear()
    (a,b) = val[i].shape
    X = np.arange(0, b)
    Y = np.arange(0, a)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    Z = val[i]
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        vmin = 900, vmax = 1430, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 60)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 280)
    ax.set_zlim(900, 1430)
    ax.view_init(azim=10, elev=20) 
    ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
    ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

return surf

# Add animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, data, fargs=(X, Y, Z, surf),  
    frames=val.size, interval=0.05  , blit=False, repeat=False)

# Full screen window
figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug (see here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/750/). The workaround is to clear the axes manually by removing all the objects.

You'll need to import the class that contains the surface so you can refer to it: `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection`

Then, replace `ax.clear()` with

```
artists = ax.findobj(match = Poly3DCollection)
for obj in artists:
    obj.remove()
```